# history.push throwing error when redirecting

Tags: react-hooks

I am here getting auth-details from localstorage in a react component, and if there are auth-details, it should redirect to the /panel route. It works, but throws this error after redirecting:

**Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.**

Here is the relevant code:

```
    const [auth] = useContext(AuthContext);
    const history = useHistory();

    if (auth) {
        history.push('/panel');
    }
```

I also tried using Redirect but it did nothing.
What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (auth) {
        history.push('/panel');
    }
},[auth]);
```

Did you try putting it into a useEffect?